# Suppress dates in diff -urN

Tags: diff

I am using `diff -urN` to compare two directories and create a patch, something like:

```
diff -urN ../resources-original/ogc ogc > ../../../src/main/patches/ogc.patch
```

The patch contains dates in `---` and `+++` lines:

```
--- ../resources-original/ogc/wms/1.3.0/capabilities_1_3_0.xsd  Sun Jul 22 03:59:38 2012
+++ ogc/wms/1.3.0/capabilities_1_3_0.xsd    Sun Jun 12 19:59:29 2016
```

Is there a possibility to suppress these dates?

Comment: They are part of the output format. If you really don't want to disclose the date (but why!?), replace these dates with dummy values. This reduces the usefulness of the patch, though; if a user neels to perform a manual merge, the dates may be useful for deciding which hunks to take.

Comment: @tripleee I generate and apply these patches automatically in builds, they are not intended for manual usage at all. Patches are checked into version control system, this is why I don't want trivial changes (like dates). This has nothing to do with "disclosing".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like

```
awk '/^(---|\+\+\+)/ { sub("  " $(NF-5) " " $(NF-4) " " $(NF-3) " " $(NF-2) " "$(NF-1) " " $NF, "  Thu Jan 1 00:00:00 1970") }1'
```